# Animated GIF doesn't load in <img src""/>

Tags: php, gif, loader, animated-gif, preloader

I'm creating an exit page for processing payments through Paypal. Now the problem is that I want display an animated GIF which doesn't load inside . I only get the static image. I've tried to add a preloading function onLoad() but nothing...

I would keep this structure

- html
- logo
- message
- animated gif (loader)

This is my code

```
  <?php
  echo "<html>\n";
  echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
  echo "<body style=\"background:#313B54\" onLoad=\" document.form.submit();\">\n";
  echo "<center style=\"height:100%\">\n";
  echo "<img style=\"display:block; margin-top:35px\" src=\"".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/lib/gateways/ux/kleeia-logo.png\"/>\n";
  echo "<h3 style=\"color:#fff; margin-top:35px\">Please wait, your payment is being processed.</h3>\n";
  echo "<img src=\"".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/lib/gateways/ux/kleeia-loader.gif\"/>\n";
  echo "</center>\n";
  echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"form\" action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

  foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
     echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\">";
  }
  echo "</form>\n";
  echo "</body></html>\n"; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Note: I'm working with wordpress.

Comment: is the gif massively huge in size, by any chance?

Comment: It's just 8k. Is it fine?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. And you can, for instance, drag the gif into your browser window and it will be animated? I'm just trying to ensure that your issue isn't w/ the gif itself.

Comment: Yes it works. Tried right now...

Comment: A further information, I'm working on localhost. Could be it an issue?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be an issue.